# Couldn't find a related Android.mk template on android source tree

Tags: android-source

I am reading the android platform-build docs with gnu makefile(Android.mk) from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/build-system.html.

Now I met an issue I didn't find a related template example?

```
<h3><a name="templates"/>How to add another component to the build - Android.mk templates</h3>
<p>You have a new library, a new app, or a new executable.  For each of the
common types of modules, there is a corresponding file in the templates
directory.  It will usually be enough to copy one of these, and fill in your
own values.  Some of the more esoteric values are not included in the
templates, but are instead just documented here, as is the documentation
on using custom tools to generate files.</p>
<p>Mostly, you can just look for the TODO comments in the templates and do
what it says.  Please remember to delete the TODO comments when you're done
to keep the files clean.  The templates have minimal documentation in them,
because they're going to be copied, and when that gets stale, the copies just
won't get updated.  So read on...</p>
<h4>Apps</h4>
<p>Use the <code>templates/apps</code> file.</p>
<p>This template is pretty self-explanitory.  See the variables below for more
details.</p>
```

As sections mentioned above I assume there are somethings named 'templates' directory for
a library, apps ... But I couldn't find that in android source tree.

Could anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

The examples are not located in a `templates` subfolder, but in the same directory as `build-system.html`:

[binary.mk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/binary.mk), [shared_library.mk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/shared_library.mk), [java_library.mk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/java_library.mk), and many more.

**Note**: Android is switching from the Makefile-based build system to [Soong](https://source.android.com/setup/build). You might want to consider switching, too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Examples are helpful for understanding how 'make' works in android. Yeah, switching to Soong is a good option if you want to move forward for a future Android version. I just felt a little confusing when I was reading this doc, and that's the background why I posted a question...